# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I am getting a run time error. As soon as I click on login button, the page gets transferred to home page.

The same code I had used previously in another application and it worked fine. But now using this code again in a new application lands me up in the aforesaid error.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code for "login.java"

```
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    forgot_password=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.forgot_password);
    text_view_2_login=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_2_login);

    username_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_login);
    password_login=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_login);

    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);

    forgot_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),checkEmail.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    text_view_2_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),sign_up.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s1=username_login.getText().toString();
            String s2=password_login.getText().toString();

            if(s1.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your email address",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else if(s2.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                Boolean check=db.email_password(s1,s2);
                if(check)
                {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),gameHome.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid username or password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the full error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.tictactoe_new, PID: 24511
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean
>   com.example.tictactoe_new.databaseHelper.email_password(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.tictactoe_new.login$3.onClick(login.java:68)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5215)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21196)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)

Comment: read the error and the error has told you what is wrong very clearly

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check `Boolean` with `null`; that's the reason it throws *Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Boolean' on a null object reference*

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    ...
    //Check whether db.email_password return null in any case
    Boolean check=db.email_password(s1,s2)!=null?true:false;
    if(check){
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
     }
});
```